can't make a multiple selecting in treeview tkinter
I'm trying to make a multiple selector with treeview in tkinter. I've read about selectmode=tkinter.EXTENDED and selectmode=tkinter.NONE. With the first one, it doesn't let choose multiple elements, and with the second one it lets but the selection is invisible.
This is the snippet of code (notice that the module login is a user-defined module, not important for the issue):
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.scrolledtext
import tkinter.ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("FBTA-BATF")
root.geometry("900x420")

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

conf_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text = "Configuración")
conf_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

tree = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(conf_frame,show="tree", height=5, selectmode=tkinter.EXTENDED)
cat = tree.insert('', 'end',text= "Hello")
cat2 = tree.insert('', 'end',text= "Bye")

tree.grid(row=5, column=1)


Have you tried running this as-written? It throws an AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ttk'. If you want to import ttk, you should use from tkinter import ttk and then prefix those widgets accordingly, e.g. ttk.Treeview. Even after fixing that, this won't run because categories is undefined.

yes, just rewrite "tkinter.ttk." and it works

i will edit and paste the whole code

We don't need all of your code, just enough to reproduce the problem. Take a second to look over what makes a [mre]

there it is, sorry for that :(

When I run the code I'm able to select both elements. Are you clicking on "Hello" and then shift-clicking on "Bye"?

You're missing a call to root.mainloop(), but other than that this appears to be working the way you want. @BryanOakley may be on to something - if you want to select multiple items you'll need to hold down either Shift or Ctrl.

i'm using Ubuntu 24.04, it may be a bug so. When I select both, it catches, but they remain white and can't see what you've selected.

It works fine in my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with Python 3.12.3.

SOLVED: needed to chose all the elements with the CTRL key pressed
